# how to set up manytomany filtering if 2 or more conditions are selected?

Tags: python, filter, many-to-many

I need to display all values ​​if 2 or more values ​​are selected. in my code, if one value is selected,

it works, if several, it does not work

```
if autosave.mail_type:
    if not (autosave.mail_type == 1 or autosave.mail_type == '1'):
        query &= Q(mail__type_mail=autosave.mail_type)
if autosave.type_of_number:
    if not (autosave.type_of_number == '2' or autosave.type_of_number == 2):
        query &= Q(number__type_number=autosave.type_of_number)
if autosave.emulator:
    query &= Q(emulator=autosave.emulator)
if autosave.resident:
    query &= Q(resident=int(autosave.resident))
if autosave.geo_id:
    geo_query = Q()
    for geo in autosave.geo_id.all():
        geo_query |= Q(geo=geo)
    query &= geo_query
autosave_options = AutoSaveOptions.objects.filter(manager_id=user_id)
if autosave_options:
    print(autosave_options)
    for autosave_option in autosave_options:
        if autosave_option.options_value:
            query &= Q(options=autosave_option.options_value)
```

`(AND: ('exchange', 1), ('options', <OptionsValue: Бизнес>), ('options', <OptionsValue: Бизнес>))`